# Can we recover a deleted server for Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We accidentally deleted our production server for Azure SQL database (the server, not just a database). How do we recover the server?

Comment: Were you able to recover the server ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but you need to open a support ticket - upper right-hand corner in the Azure Portal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I did that but I had to buy support subscription for that.

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea how you deleted the production server, but when you try to delete in the azure portal, it will remind you that deleting server is irreversible and all the items will gone permanently. So unfortunate that you cannot recover it.

[image]

Comment: If I raise a support ticket ticket would they be able to restore the deleted server?

Answer (score -1):

In the Management Portal ( http://manage.windowsazure.com ) select the SQL Databases task on the left, and Deleted Databases on the top.

[image]

Comment: This Tab will not have the deleted SQL Server and associated Database backups