# Is it possible to restore a deleted Sql Server instance in Azure?

Tags: azure, database-restore

I recently deleted a SQL server instance (with 2 sql databases) on my azure portal. I would like to know if there is a way for me to restore the deleted SQL server and the corresponding Sql databases.

I would appreciate any help/direction in this regard.

Thanks

Uma

Comment: You're referring to SQL Database service? If so: You can either restore from your backups, or if you have none of those, open a support ticket. That's about it.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete SQL Server from portal, you will get a warning : **Warning! Deleting xxx is irreversible.** So the best solution to this is  to open a support ticket.

You could also refer to [Can we recover a deleted server for Azure SQL Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977481/can-we-recover-a-deleted-server-for-azure-sql-database/35006859#35006859) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft might be able recover the databases under these conditions:

- Another SQL Server with the same name was NOT created
- Less than 7 days passed since the deletion
- The Region, SQL Server and Resource Group name must be known

You need to log a support ticket. If the server can be recovered, it will be restored. The databases were not restored in my case, but could be recovered using the [normal method for recovering a deleted SQL Database within a SQL server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups#deleted-database-restore-using-the-azure-portal).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to restore an sql server by contacting MS support through a support ticket in the Azure portal.

Key things that must be available:

1. The name of the Sql server and database
2. The resource group name and time of deletion.
3. You should not have created another sql server resource with the same name in an attempt to recover the sql server.

I had an ARM template of the resource group that I exported from the portal. Without this I would not have remembered the names of the resources above.

Key takeaways:

1. Ensure that users that is not the subscription holder cannot delete resources.
2. Export ARM templates for all RG's - this saved my b**.

Thanks to the MS team for helping me out so quickly! They helped me out within an hour! Great service!